# pthread_mutex_lock.c:62: __pthread_mutex_lock: Assertion `mutex->__data.__owner == 0' failed

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, c++11

I received that error:

> pthread_mutex_lock.c:62: __pthread_mutex_lock: Assertion `mutex->_*data.*_owner == 0' failed.

And I cannot found any cause of that. However I'm not sure about the following piece of code:

Declarations:

```
std::mutex lock;
std::condition_variable cond;
```

Sequence of locks & unlocks:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(lock);

cond.wait(lk);

lock.unlock();
```

If I remove this sequence - everything works fine, but without any protection. I'm not sure if I use `unique_lock` properly.

Comment: For the future, please try to post short, but complete programs - http://sscce.org/ :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::unique_lock` and other locks acquire a mutex in the constructor and release it in the destructor.
You called `lock.unlock()` in your code manually, making it called effectively twice.

After removing that statement your code should work properly.

Comment: Alternatively, call `lk.unlock()`, so the lock knows that the mutex has been unlocked. (And perhaps call the mutex something other than "lock", so you don't confuse it with a lock).