# Why am I receiving a lock assertion failure for a simple boost producer/consumer program?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm working on creating a simple threaded producer/consumer example using separate classes, c++ standard library deques, and boost threads on Linux. I'm passing a shared buffer, lock, and condition variables by reference as member variables to my classes. The threads start up ok, but typically crash at a random time due to a lock assertion error.

```
main: ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:80: __pthread_mutex_lock: Assertion `mutex->__data.__owner == 0' failed.
```

Here's how I'm starting the threads in main

```
std::deque<double> buf;
boost::condition_variable_any buf_has_space;
boost::condition_variable_any buf_has_data;
boost::mutex buf_lock;

boost::thread producerThread(load_func, &buf, &buf_has_space, &buf_has_data, &buf_lock);
boost::thread consumerThread(consume_func, &buf, &buf_has_space, &buf_has_data, &buf_lock);

producerThread.join();
consumerThread.join();
```

`producerThread` and `consumerThread` initialize and run instances of `myProducer` and `myConsumer`.

Relevant code from `myProducer`:

```
void myProducer::add_to_buffer(){
    //Main loop
    for (int i=0; i<100000; i++){
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(*buffer_lock);
        while (buffer->size() == max_size){
            buffer_has_space->wait(*buffer_lock);
        }
        buffer->push_back(i);
        buffer_has_data->notify_one();
        buffer_lock -> unlock();
    }

    //Consumer will stop when it sees -1
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(*buffer_lock);
    while (buffer->size() == max_size){
        buffer_has_space->wait(*buffer_lock);
    }
    buffer->push_back(-1.0);
    buffer_has_data->notify_one();
    buffer_lock -> unlock();
}
```

Relevant code from `myConsumer`:

```
void myConsumer::load_from_buffer(){
    double current = 0;
    while (current != -1.0) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(*buffer_lock);
        while (buffer->size() == 0){
            buffer_has_data->wait(*buffer_lock);
        }
        current = buffer->front();
        buffer->pop_front();
        buffer_has_space->notify_one();
        buffer_lock->unlock();
        std::cout << current <<"\n";
    }
}
```

I've looked at these questions:

[pthread_mutex_lock.c:62: __pthread_mutex_lock: Assertion `mutex->__data.__owner == 0' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239999/pthread-mutex-lock-c62-pthread-mutex-lock-assertion-mutex-data-owner)

[Pthread mutex assertion error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105745/pthread-mutex-assertion-error)

However, the program is crashing before my classes are deconstructed, and each lock is matched with an unlock in the same thread.

Comment: `buffer_lock -> unlock();` - perhaps the `scoped_lock` is a little peeved when it tries to do exactly what its name implies (lock for scope) since you already unlocked the mutex manually. I.e. it tries to unlock that which it *thinks* it owns, and can't. The scoped lock should be the object of the waiter's desire; not the bare mutex.

Comment: @WhozCraig, you're right! I commented out the the unlock lines, and now it runs reliably. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the lock owned by a lock guard (scoped_lock) it's an error to manually manipulate the lock.

If you **must** manipulate the lock before the end of the scope, you can do so on the `scoped_lock` itself:

```
lock.unlock();  // instead of buffer_lock -> unlock();
```